# Modifying model's observed properties in action Ember

Tags: ember.js

I have a search results page with the retrieved search results stored in the model as results. on the same page, I have a button to check all the results for extraction.

I have a property named checked and initially, it is set to `false`in the button action I want to change this property on each result to true.

this is my action

```
checkAll(){
      this.controller.get("model.results").map(doc=>{
        doc.checked = true;
      })
    }
```

but I keep getting this error:

> Assertion Failed: You must use Ember.set() to set the `checked` property (of [object Object]) to `true`.

I don't how to use `Ember.set()` only on that property. and I don't know if this is the right way to go about this as I'm new to ember.

any help would be much appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use Ember's [set](https://emberjs.com/api/ember/2.16/classes/@ember%2Fobject/methods/set?anchor=set) function to set properties to an object.

Like this, `Ember.set(doc, 'checked', true);`.